# SQL Server trigger to determine crud source

Tags: sql-server

I have a web application and the database it is on my client building. I want to know if the CRUD (create, update, delete) actions made from my application of "someone" for any reason, done it from SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a trigger for update/insert on the tables you want to audit, then adapt the following code from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx) on `AppName()` :

```
DECLARE @CurrentApp varchar(40)
SET @CurrentApp = APP_NAME()
IF @CurrentApp <> 'SQL Server Management Studio - Query'
PRINT 'This process was not started by a SQL Server Management Studio query session.';
```

I believe it might be open to spoofing though, as I think programs can specify the application name in the connection string.